# Learning representation theory of real reductive lie groups

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I am interested in any sources that can be helpful for learning the representation theory of real reductive groups. I am currently reading Wallach book, but I feel that I don't understand the subject properly and want to find an alternative.
(this is a copy of the question on MO: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163180/learning-representation-theory-of-real-reductive-lie-groups?))